# Parse android application query: saving retrieved data

Tags: android, parsing

I use parse.com to get an Integer, which saves how many gold a user has. 
I tried this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("gold");
query.whereEqualTo("username", username);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
       //how can I save the gold as an integer?
    } else {
        Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
});
```

Comment: What is the problem or query

Answer (score 0):

That depends key you used to store the gold in the `ParseObject`. Once you have that, you can just replace your comment with:

```
int score = scoreList.get(0).getInt(<keyForGold>);
```

Comment: What is the keyForGold?

Comment: What key are you using to store the value for the user's gold in the `ParseObject`?

Comment: So now Yo can get the int. but if I try to give it out in a text view it crashes.

Comment: what's the exception?